# resursive sudoku solver using struct

Tags: c#, recursion, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, sudoku

I am trying out this [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sudoku/problem?h_r=internal-search) using c#.

```
class Solution
{
    static int LEN = 9;
    static int[] nums = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    public struct Sudoku
    {
        public int[,] grid;

        public Sudoku(int[,] grid) : this()
        {
            this.n = n;
            this.grid = new int[9, 9];

            for (int r = 0; r < LEN; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < LEN; c++)
                {
                    this.grid[r, c] = grid[r, c];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static bool isValid(int row, int col, int n, Sudoku s)
    {
        // check horizontally
        for (int c = 0; c < LEN; c++)
        {
            if (s.grid[row, c] == n) return false;
        }

        // check vertically
        for (int r = 0; r < LEN; r++)
        {
            if (s.grid[r, col] == n) return false;
        }

        // check box
        for (int r = row / 3 * 3; r < row / 3 * 3 + 3; r++)
        {
            for (int c = col / 3 * 3; c < col / 3 * 3 + 3; c++)
            {
                if (s.grid[r, c] == n) return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    static bool solve(Sudoku s)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < LEN; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < LEN; c++)
            {
                if (s.grid[r, c] != 0) continue;

                foreach (int n in nums)
                {
                    if (isValid(r, c, n, s))
                    {
                        s.grid[r, c] = n;
                        print_sudoku(s);
                        if (solve(s)) return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

At first I tried using recursion with a multi-dimensional array, but I found   that when sudoku is not solvable, this line doesn't revert the numbers that I wrongly put in:

```
if(solve(s)) return true;
```

So, I used a struct instead, which is a value type and passed by value.

However, in struct Sudoku, I am using array which causes same problem again.

Please give me some pointers so that numbers are passed by value.

> **The answer was simply erase number after each loop**

```
static bool solve(int[,] grid){
    for (int r = 0; r < LEN; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < LEN; c++){
            if (grid[r,c] != 0) continue;
            foreach (int n in nums){
                if (isValid(r, c, n, grid)) {
                    int[,] ngrid = new int[9,9];
                    for (int nr = 0; nr < LEN; nr++){
                        for (int nc = 0; nc < LEN; nc++){
                            ngrid[nr,nc] = grid[nr, nc];
                        }
                    }
                    ngrid[r, c] = n;
                    if(solve(ngrid)) return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    print_sudoku(grid);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my solution below.  I put a blank in a cell when not solvable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sudoku
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SUDOKU sudoku = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            sudoku =  new SUDOKU(this);
        }

        private void Solve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SUDOKU.Solve();
        }

        private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(sudoku);
            sudoku.Dispose();
            sudoku = new SUDOKU(this);
        }
    }
    public class SUDOKU : Panel
    {
        public const int TOP_MARGIN = 50;
        public const int LEFT_MARGIN = 50;

        static List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>();

        static List<List<Cell>> rows = null;
        static List<List<Cell>> columns = null;
        static List<List<Cell>> boxes = null;

        public SUDOKU(Form form)
        {
            form.Controls.Add(this);
            this.Left = LEFT_MARGIN;
            this.Top = TOP_MARGIN;

            this.Width = (2 * LEFT_MARGIN) + (9 * Cell.WIDTH);
            this.Height = (2 * TOP_MARGIN) + (9 * Cell.HEIGHT);

            rows = (new string('\0',9)).Select(x => new List<Cell>()).ToList();
            columns = (new string('\0', 9)).Select(x => new List<Cell>()).ToList();
            boxes = (new string('\0', 9)).Select(x => new List<Cell>()).ToList();


            for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
            {
                Cell newCell = new Cell(i);
                this.Controls.Add(newCell);
            }

        }
        public static void Solve()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
            {
                if (cells[i].textBox.Text != "")
                {
                    cells[i].value = int.Parse(cells[i].textBox.Text);
                }
            }
            RecursiveSolve(0);
        }
        static Boolean RecursiveSolve(int index)
        {
            Boolean solved = false;

            Cell cell = cells[index];

            if (cell.value != null)
            {
                if (index == 80)
                {
                    solved = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    solved = RecursiveSolve(index + 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
                {
                    if (!rows[cell.row].Where(x => x.value == i).Any())
                    {
                        if (!columns[cell.column].Where(x => x.value == i).Any())
                        {
                            if (!boxes[cell.box].Where(x => x.value == i).Any())
                            {
                                cell.value = i;
                                cell.textBox.Text = i.ToString();
                                cell.textBox.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                                cell.textBox.SelectionFont = new Font("Ariel", 30);
                                if (index == 80)
                                {
                                    solved = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    solved = RecursiveSolve(index + 1);
                                    if (solved)
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        cell.value = null;
                                        cell.textBox.Text = "";
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return solved;
        }

        public class Cell : Panel
        {
            public const int WIDTH = 100;
            public const int HEIGHT = 100;

            public Dictionary<int, int> boxDict = new Dictionary<int, int>() {
                {0,0}, {1,0},{2,0},{3,1},{4,1},{5,1},{6,2},{7,2},{8,2},
                {9,0}, {10,0},{11,0},{ 12,1},{13,1},{14,1},{15,2},{16,2},{17,2},
                {18,0}, {19,0},{20,0},{21,1},{22,1},{23,1},{24,2},{25,2},{26,2},
                {27,3}, {28,3},{29,3},{30,4},{31,4},{32,4},{33,5},{34,5},{35,5},
                {36,3}, {37,3},{38,3},{39,4},{40,4},{41,4},{42,5},{43,5},{44,5},
                {45,3}, {46,3},{47,3},{48,4},{49,4},{50,4},{51,5},{52,5},{53,5},
                {54,6}, {55,6},{56,6},{57,7},{58,7},{59,7},{60,8},{61,8},{62,8},
                {63,6}, {64,6},{65,6},{66,7},{67,7},{68,7},{69,8},{70,8},{71,8},
                {72,6}, {73,6},{74,6},{75,7},{76,7},{77,7},{78,8},{79,8},{80,8},
            };

            public int index = 0;
            public int row = 0;
            public int column = 0;
            public int box = 0;
            public int? value = null;
            public RichTextBox textBox = new RichTextBox();

            public Cell() { }

            public Cell(int index)
            {
                cells.Add(this);
                this.index = index;
                this.row = index / 9;
                this.column = index % 9;
                this.box = boxDict[index];

                this.Left = SUDOKU.LEFT_MARGIN + (column * WIDTH);
                this.Top = SUDOKU.TOP_MARGIN + (row * HEIGHT);
                this.Width = WIDTH;
                this.Height = HEIGHT;

                this.Controls.Add(textBox);
                textBox.Left = 0;
                textBox.Top = 0;
                textBox.Width = WIDTH;
                textBox.Height = HEIGHT;
                textBox.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                textBox.SelectionFont = new Font("Ariel", 30);
                //textBox.Text = index.ToString();
                textBox.Multiline = false;

                rows[row].Add(this);
                columns[column].Add(this);
                boxes[box].Add(this);
            }
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            cells = new List<Cell>(); 
            rows = new List<List<Cell>>();
            columns = new List<List<Cell>>(); ;
            boxes = new List<List<Cell>>();
        }
    }
}
```